# How do I set specific y position, width and height without diving into code?

Tags: swift

A designer I'm working with wants to have a UIImageView be at a specific y position, with a specific width/height depending on the iphone size. I've done research and I haven't been able to find anything online that allows me to do so with constraints on the story board. I want to avoid having to use code because throughout the rest of the app there are a lot of similar situations. In the past I've made different storyboards for each phone size to accommodate for the specificity our clients request, but I want to avoid doing this because it feels like bad practice. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why does setting constraints for the width and height not work for you?  It's set in points, not pixels.  So it will adjust for different sizes on its own.

Comment: to be honest, i don't really have a good answer, i just thought my code would get cluttered by having so many "if screen size == x", and wanted to see if it could be done in strictly the story board.

Comment: That is what auto layout for. To cover multiple size of devices.

Comment: the problem i feel, is that when drafting up what it'll look like in the storyboards, by setting all of the widths / heights in code, i will have to build and run in order to see what it'll look like.

Comment: No no, there is a preview pane you can switch to in the Assistant Editor to see what auto layout will do for different screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be completely handled in the Interface Builder.  Follow the steps below.

1) Add your `UIImageView` to the `ViewController`

2) Set constraints for `Width`, `Height`, `Vertically Align` and `Horizontally Align`
[image]
[image]

3) You can adjust the Y position in the Size Inspector of the view.

[image]

4) Now switch to Assistant Editor and choose 'Preview' and add different screen sizes to see the auto layout in action.

[image]

All of this will set a static image size of 250x200, horizontally centered, and vertically at 1/4 of the screen height.

Comment: so, for example, if i wanted y to be 74 for the iphone 4, 104, for the iphone 5...and so on, and the width/height to be 60 for the iphone 4, 66 for the iphone 5, and 70 for the iphone 6 and so on, then it would be better to do so in code and use the preview functionality to test it?edit: in summary, it would be better to use outlets to govern the specificity?

Comment: Also something to note, is that the app will only be in portrait, I will never have to worry about landscape.

Comment: That is how i like to do it.  I've ready many tutorials on size classes, but still have yet to grasp them well.  Here is a tutorial that got me the closest and i now understand it, but still prefer to use constraint outlets in code.  https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

Comment: ok thank you, I thought there was some trick and was avoiding using it b/c I couldn't figure it out. I will try it out.

Comment: hey @TheValyreanGroup, where would be the best place to set these values for the constraints, ViewDidLoad()?

Comment: Yes, set your new values there.  And then you'll need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`  to update the constraints.

Comment: i'm having problems with the preview; after adding the code to set the constraints, the preview isn't showing the real results. Only when i build / run it on a test phone does it look how it's supposed to. Any clue why?

Comment: If you do it with code, preview will not work except for the default constraints you've set.

Answer (score 0):

Little-known capability of constraints are that you can set view positions, or in your case sizes, by way of ratios against other views.

With just your image view selected, the tie-fighter :) constraints button lets you specify absolute positions & sizes: do that to set your desired y-position. But then select both your image view and its enclosing parent view, then the pop up for that same button now enables the equal height/width buttons. Add those constraints and then edit the constraint to change the 1:1 ratio to whatever ratio you need.

Excuse my lack of screenshots, posting from my phone.

Comment: with ratios, it sounds like things are still left a little ambiguous in terms of positioning. the client I'm working with wants the dimensions exactly how they want them....unfortunately.